# Typescript can not find modules

Tags: typescript, node-modules, typescript1.8, tsc, tsconfig

My server `.ts` files are complaining of not finding the modules and the typings, though I installed the modules and checked the `node_modules`.

This is my project structure: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvDcZ.png)

The errors I get : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Gau.png)

The `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    "typings"
    ],
    "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "./typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: are you using `tscg` to compile the code?

Comment: no..............................

Comment: refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-with-globs

Answer (score 0):

`filesGlob` are not yet supported in native typescript ([github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927))

My suggestion would be to remove filesGlob section as it looks like you do not actually need it, and instead:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser/**"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.